# does not not_null ever make sense?

Tags: php

I have inherited some code in which the previous coder wrote this:

```
    if (!not_null($page)) {
       die('<b>Error!</b><br><b>Unable to determine the page link!<br><br>');
    }
```

Is there any advantage to this, as opposed to just saying:
    if (is_null($page))

It seems unnecessarily confusing to me.

Comment: `=== null` beats is_null, right?

Comment: Where have you seen `not_null` ? I dont see it in php docs.

Comment: kinda wierd... ofcourse i prefer using `=== null` and `!== null` instead of calling the functions...

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: Yes; there's no function call overhead.

Comment: ok, never mind. I just realized that not_null is not a php function. The guy had written his own function called not_null. Still, it makes no sense to not just use is_null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`not_null` must be a local function.

It is **not** a standard PHP function.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing what `not_null` does, it is impossible to say. Since `not_null` is a user-defined function, it could be doing **anything**

If, after checking in to things, you find that `not_null` is doing a simple comparison, you *could* refactor the code in the name of readability:

```
if (is_null($page))
    die('<p><strong>Error!</strong><br>Unable to determine the page link!</p>')
```

OR

```
if ($page === null)
    die('<p><strong>Error!</strong>Unable to determine the page link!</p>')
```

P.S. - don't use `<b>` -- use `<strong>` instead. Also, when you need multiple line breaks, use a `<p>` instead of multiple `<br>`. Your sample code has an unclosed `<b>` tag on the error message.

**Documentation**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php

Comment: For clarification, why use strong over b?

Comment: Tags like `<b>` and `<i>` are poorly semantic considering HTML as a structural markup language. **Most often**, semantically meaningful tags like `<strong>` and `<em>` are the better choice. All that said, if you just want to make the font-face bold, you can use `font-weight: bold` in css on a semantically neutral tag like `<div>` and be able to change that typeface later without looking at editing markup. These reasons why you don't use inline CSS are the same for not using `<b>` and `<i>`. Contrary to popular belief, the tags are **NOT** deprecated.

Comment: @Chris, that makes sense.  Man, they taught us crap in school.

Comment: @Chris: thanks for the good reminders about the <b> and <br> tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `not_null` function in PHP I believe.

**What should you use?**

Use `=== null` or `!== null` instead of ***making a call to function*** explicitly.

Comment: or use `is_null(...)` or in some cases `empty(...)`

Comment: This advice sounds premature to me. It sounds like the OP hasn't investigated not_null and verified that it really does just check for `!==null`, so they should leave it in place until they understand it.

Comment: I edited my earlier comment for clarity, but to expand: You correctly said that not_null isn't a standard PHP function. That means that it's defined somewhere in their code, and it could be doing any number of other checks, or have all sorts of side effects that are necessary for the program to function. It would be dangerous to replace it with other code until the OP knows what the function is actually doing.

Comment: For the record, favoring a `=== null` equivalency over the more semantically appropriate `is_null` is a wholly unnecessary micro-optimization. Readability is far more important than the nearly immeasurable microseconds you might save by testing the equivalency.

Comment: @octern: I think I get you this time, this is what you can answer with provided information though, my point is why waste cpu cycle in calling a function when you already can do `!==null`

Comment: I think the point here is that no one except the OP has any idea what the function `not_null` is doing. You can assume, but as we all know...

Comment: @Chris I got the impression that the OP doesn't know what not_null is doing either. At first they assumed it was a built-in function, so they wouldn't have looked for its source. I don't see anything saying they checked it out and determined what it does. But yes... if Blaster got the impression that they had done so, then Blaster's answer is totally reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It actually seems worse to do so because one can simply write in the if statement:
`if($page==null)` which evaluates quicker than using this function.  You can also try `if(!$page)` which will evaluate quickly as well.

Comment: It depends on what's needed here. Both of those tests will return true if $page is `null`, but also if it's `0`, `""`, or `array()`. If you want to test whether something is actually null (or unset), you need to use either `===null` or `is_null()` .